# xfce made eclipse look weird

Tags: xfce, eclipse

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and installed XFCE 4.10.

Ever since then Eclipse looks pretty much unusable as you can see below I cannot even see the filenames of the tabs I have open because they are so faint.

Any ideas how that is caused? I even went to `Appearance` and tried to switch everything to default but Eclipse still looks super weird.

[image: scrrenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the xfce theme. So, try this link out for specific instructions on changing your theme: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939848. I know that when, I ran xbuntu some themes did not play well with the java runtime environment.